# wordpress: show all posts from selected date?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've incorporated the wordpress built in archive widget into a site I'm developing. When the user selects a month such as August 2017, I want my archive.php page to be populated with all the posts which were posted in that month and year.

I've solved what seems to be a very similar problem with the categories widget in category.php, which loads all the posts associated with the selected category using the following code:

```
<?php

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
$category_name = single_cat_title( '', false ); 

foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 

    if ( has_category( $category_name ) ) : ?>

    <p><?php the_title_attribute(); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>            
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

However I can't figure out how to achieve a similar effect but with retrieving specific posts based on their date. Any ideas?

Comment: You will need to use [WP_Query](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/using-wp_query-wordpress/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that this can be solved by simply using the post loop as long as the code is present in the archive.php file. The archive date (such as July 2017) selected from the widget by the user is saved and retrieves posts from that date only.

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
           <p><?php the_title_attribute(); ?></p>
         <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```